# sending text sms from oracle

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, sms, sms-gateway

I have an GSM Modem And I want to attach it with pc and want to send text msges from oracle database to user mobile phone.Please any one tell me is there any authentic way to send sms from oracle db to user mobiles.I want make my own gate way for this type of requirments using .net plateform like vb.net or c# please any one tell me to how can send sms from oracle by using vb.net as front end developmetn and oracle db as back end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite intriguing. There's no native way to do it and you will have to use some external tools to achieve this.

Follow [this](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=378726)

Quote-

> **Send SMS Using GSM Modem/Mobile Phone & its Supporting Software/Utility.**
>
> There are many software/utilities/Tools
>   which can do this, but here i am using a free project. In this Way,
>   Install/Configure:
>                 * Red Hat Linux Operating System
>                 * Oracle Database 8i/9.x/10.x
>                 * Gnokii - For Nokia Mobile Phone
>
> ```
>     Download    : http://gnokii.org/download/gnokii/0.6.x/gnokii-0.6.2.tar.gz
>     Install     : http://urtica.linuxnews.pl/~pkot/gnokii/gnokii.html#ch1 
>     Sample File : http://cvs.savannah.nongnu.org/viewcvs/gnokii/gnokii/Docs/sample/gnokiirc?rev=1.22
>     User Guide  : http://wiki.gnokii.org/index.php/User%27s_Guide
>
>     * Nokia Mobile Phone With Data Cable - [http://www.gnokii.org/cables.shtml]
> ```
>
> Try to Send SMS Using the Command.
>
> `$ echo "This is a test SMS using Gnokii-Linux..." | gnokii --sendsms +12052059201`
>
> Note : Message Length = 160 Characters. It Will Take 30 - 40 Seconds
>   and will send the SMS to the desired Number.
>
> To Test & Configure it in Oracle Database, you have to Create a Java
>   Class.
>
> http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/ShellCommandsFromPLSQL.php
>
> ```
> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000  
> CALL DBMS_JAVA.SET_OUTPUT(1000000);
>
> BEGIN
>   Host_Command (p_command => 'echo "This is a test SMS from Oracle Database." | gnokii --sendsms +12052059201');    
> END;    
> /
> ```

Comment: Sir I Already Have Tried successfully the gnokii setup but gnokii is not a freeware application i want some freeware idea